# Woocommerce Social Login Google verifying

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-oauth

i got **Google ID** and **Google secret** form Google API Console . and i set it in Social Login Woocommerce Plugin (YITH plugin) . but when Somebody try to login with his google account , google say **This app isn't verified** . i don't have social login problem with LinkedIn or Facebook.

[Google Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkHb8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps to verify your app
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865